# are they complete metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I need to know whether the following spaces are complete or not

1. Space of all continuos real valued functions with compact support with supnorm metric
2. The space $C^1[0,1]$ with metric $d(f,g)=max_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)-g(t)|$

Please help, I have no clue. Thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking, do you know the completion of the space of continuous real functions with compact support with regards to the supremum norm?

Comment: @AymanHourieh, I have no idea.

Comment: OK, do you know that the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous functions is also continuous?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes That I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.
Consider the sequence functions 
$$f_n(x)=\max\left\{0,\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1n\right\}$$

2.
Let $f(x)=\left\vert x-\frac12\right\vert$. Can you find functions $f_n\in C^1([0,1])$ with $\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f_n(t)-f(t)|<\frac1n$? What does that impliy?

Answer (score 1):

1. is complete. A proof you can find in baby Rudin or Stokey Lucas Prescott. 
   For 2. consider the sequence of functions  $
      f_n(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{lr}
          -x & : x <-\frac{1}{n}\\
          \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{n}{2} x^2 & : -\frac{1}{n}\leq x \leq\frac{1}{n}\\
           x & : x>\frac{1}{n}  
        \end{array}
      \right.$

Comment: Presumably you mean the space of continuous functions on a compact space in 1., which is indeed a complete space. In general, this is not the same as the space of functions with compact support (the support of a function is the closure of the set of points where $f$ takes nonzero values). The functions $f_n\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ from part 1. of Hagen von Eitzen's answer have compact support and they form a Cauchy sequence, yet they do not converge to a function with compact support.

Comment: you are right, I obviously missed that point. Hope my answer to 2. is ok tho.

Comment: The answer to 2 is almost okay. You "smoothen out" the corner of the absolute value at zero and the sequence converges uniformly to the absolute value which fails to be differentiable at $0$. The only minor point is that the problem asked about $C^1[0,1]$, not $C^{1}[-1,1]$, but that's not a big deal, just replace $f_n(x)$ by $f_{n}(x-1/2)$.