# True/false : The Space of all continiuos real valued functions with compact support with supnorm metric is complete .

Tags: metric-spaces

Is the followimg statement is  True/false

The Space of all continiuos real valued functions with compact support with supnorm metric is  complete . (True/false)

i have  found the  answer  here :
 [are they complete metric spaces?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/271475/are-they-complete-metric-spaces)

Now  my confusion is that i didn't understand the answer How  can we contradicts  this function  ?

[image]

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  No  sir  , Im preparing For NBHM exam  it is a NBHM question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints: Each $f_n$ has compact support since $x^{2}>n-1$ implies $f_n(x)=0$, Verify that $f_n(x) \to f(x) \equiv \frac 1 {1+x^{2}}$ uniformly on $\mathbb R$. Conclude that $\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy in the given space. Suppose it converges to some $g$ in the given space. Then $f_n \to f$ and $f_n \to g$ pointwise. Hence $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$. But $g$ has compact support and $f$ doesn't. This completes the proof.

Comment: Im not  getting How $ f$  does not have  compact support  i mean  u have  already take that each $f_n $ has  compact support

Comment: $f(x)=\frac 1 {1+x^{2}} \neq 0$ for any $x$.

Comment: Got its sir thanks u sir @Kavi  rama sir